# How similar is Windows Server 2003 to 2008 and later?

Tags: windows

Basically I'm going to be helping with the maintenance of a companys server but I'm not that good at Windows servers, so I'm going to be picking up a textbook and create a VM so I can start learning how to handle them. However, I don't know which version is best for me to start learning.

The company has an old 2003 server which I'll be admin'ing, but I'm having a hard time finding a bootable ISO for Windows Server 2003. I have however found one for 2008.

So my question is, how similar are 2003 and 2008? If I master 2008 will I also be able to handle 2003 with ease? Are they so different that I should focus on 2003 instead?

Follow up question, how similar is 2008 to later versions? I picked 2008 because it was the closest one to 2003 so I figured they'd be similar enough for my purpose, but perhaps I should pick up an even later version if it's not so different as to hinder me in maintaining an old 2003 version?

So basically, if I'm gonna be maintining a 2003 Windows Server, which version should I pick up (as new as possible without being totally lost when I have to get back to 2003)?

Comment: 2008 is closer to 2003 than to 2008R2. However I guess it depends on the actual technologies used. Must of them are still present in some way or the other. The server itself is only a small part. But maybe you are lucky if they have only one old server they won't bother you with AD or Domain administration.

Comment: `So my question is, how similar are 2003 and 2008?` - They're not. How close is Windows XP to Windows Vista? That's how close Windows Server 2003 is to Windows Server 2008. Additionally, Windows Server 2008 isn't that far removed from Windows Server 2008 R2 but it's a far cry from Windows Server 2012/R2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your standard plea to urge that company to replace that 2003 server.  It's so old that it's no longer receiving security patches.

That said...

Server 2003 is the same kernel as Windows XP.  Server 2008 is the same kernel as Vista.  Server 2008 R2 is the same kernel as Windows 7.  (And so on:  2012 is the same kernel as 8, 2012 R2 is the same kernel as 8.1, 2016 is the same kernel as 10.)  The server versions have similar interfaces to the desktop versions they share a kernel with.

In short:  XP optimized for performance rather than graphics and animation (PC -> Advanced -> Performance Settings -> Adjust for best performance) is probably closer to Server 2003 than Server 2008 is to Server 2003.

For example, this is the XP "Classic mode" control panel:
[image]

And this is the Server 2003 control panel:
[image]

There's more "stuff" in administrative tools, though.
[image]

That said, whether that helps you learn how to administer Server 2003 depends on what you'll be doing with the server.

(Please get them to upgrade!)

Comment: Are there more differences than the kernel used? For example will I find the server management tool in the same place and such (is it like the difference between XP control panel and Vista and up control panel where you have basically the same stuff at roughly the same place)? Preferably I wouldn't sit and have to look for programs all over the place when switching versions in the event they stand there looking over my shoulder while I fix the server. :)

Comment: I edited the post with some pictures I found online (I decommissioned my last 2003 box over a year ago).